# How to wrap long lines into label control?

Tags: vb.net, label

I have content of 50-60 words in label and it goes beyond my groupbox where I put it, so I need to wrap it so it can be accommodate within groupbox.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just Set the `AutoSize` property of the label to `False`, then reposition then label to the size you need